# how to hide back button in React-navigation/react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, react-navigation

I would like to hide the Back button in the top-left corner, but I don't have any idea how to do it with react-navigation or react-native.

Just tried to use `static navigationOptions = { header: null }` but the `< Back` button was still alive.

I was using `Modal` and it works, but I want to know how to hide `< Back` button without using `Modal`.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're using a StackNavigator and that you don't want a header.

You need to use `headerMode: none` in the StackNavigatorConfig.
For example:

```
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: Home },
    ModalScreen: { screen: Modal },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
  }
);
```

More info in the [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html).

Answer (score 9):

Using `headerLeft: () => <></>` works great in iOS, but in Android was still displaying the default back button.

I was able to hide it by adding the `headerBackVisible: false` on the **screenOptions** of the Stack Navigator or you could include it on the **options** for every Stack Screen.

More info at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerbackvisible

Comment: headerBackVisible: false finally fixed this issue for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: that's working for native-stack.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the react navigation version you're using, try this

```
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator(
{
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home },
  ModalScreen: { screen: Modal },
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  header: null
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is StackNavigator default config, go to StackNavigator:

defaultNavigationOptions: {
     header: null,
},

Answer (score 1):

```
    const Stack = createStackNavigator(); 
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
```

**createStackNavigator** is a function that returns an object containing 2 properties: Screen and Navigator. Both of them are React components used for configuring the navigator.
Now below Stack.Navigator, you can place your screens using `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />`. In name, you can give any name, and in component give the name of your component.